# how to solve interface {} is string, not []uint8 in golang?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I want to do the read and write operation in the json file. I made a program for this But there is an error which occure while Unmarshalling the datathe code is given below:-

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
)

type Page struct {
  Id           int    `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
  Title        string `json:"title" bson:"title"`
  Type         string `json:"type" bson:"type"`
  Description  string `json:"description" bson:"description"`
  ProfileImage string `json:"profile_image" bson:"profile_image"`
  DateTime     int64  `json:"date_time" bson:"date_time"`
  Author       string `json:"author" bson:"author"`
  Status       int    `json:"status" bson:"status"`
  Slug         string `json:"slug" bson:"slug"`
}

func main() {
   plan, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("page.json")
   var data interface{}
   err := json.Unmarshal(plan, &data)
   if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
   }
   if sl, ok := data.([]interface{}); ok {
     counter := 0
      for _, val := range sl {
        counter++
        md, _ := val.(map[string]interface{})
        md["_id"] = counter
        fmt.Println(md["_id"])
        for _, k := range md {
            // fmt.Println(k.([]byte))
            rankings := Page{}
            err = json.Unmarshal(k.([]uint8), &rankings)
            if err != nil {
                // nozzle.printError("opening config file", err.Error())
            }

            rankingsJson, _ := json.Marshal(rankings)
            err = ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", rankingsJson, 0644)
            fmt.Printf("%+v", rankings)
        }
      }
   }
}
```

It gives me the error of

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not []uint8
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>
> main.main()
>
> /home/iron/go/src/test/json_object_read/main.go:38 +0x545

Edited :-

```
[{
    "title": "Home Page",
    "type": "Home Page",
    "description": "On this Page you will get all the little discription about the all sections of the theme.",
    "profile_image": "/home.png",
    "author": "Bookingkoala",
    "status": 1,
    "slug": "home-page"
},
{
    "title": "Booking Page",
    "type": "Booking",
    "description": "On this page you will do Booking in 60 seconds",
    "profile_image": "/Booking.png",
    "author": "Bookingkoala",
    "status": 1,
    "slug": "booking-page"
},
{
    "title":"Gift Cards",
    "type":"Cards",
    "description":"On this page you will get the Gift cards on Special Days like:- Mother Day, Friendship Day, Father Day, etc.",
    "profile_image":"/Gift.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"gift-cards"
},
{
    "title":"Contact Us",
    "type":"Contact Information",
    "description":"On Contact Us Page you will get the Contact information of the merchant.",
    "profile_image":"/Contact.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"contact-us" 
},
{
    "title":"Services",
    "type":"Services",
    "description":"This service page will show you that which services bookingkoala has been provided",
    "profile_image":"/services.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"services"
},
{
    "title":"About Us",
    "type":"About the organisation",
    "description":"Most are targeted towards shareholders and aren't interesting for their customers, but Adidas breaks the mold.While most of the information is still geared towards shareholders, the athletic company's presentation is easily digestible and nicely organized.",
    "profile_image":"/aboutus.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"about-us"
},
{
    "title":"Referrals",
    "type":"referrals",
    "description":"This will give you the money in you wallte on each share.",
    "profile_image":"/referrals.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"referrals"
},
{
    "title":"Login/SignUp",
    "type":"Login/SignUp",
    "description":"Via This page you will enter to the theme.",
    "profile_image":"/login.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"login"
},
{
    "title":"Terms/Services",
    "type":"Terms/Services",
    "description":"This page tells you the term and conditions.",
    "profile_image":"/services_and_terms.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"terms"
},
{
    "title":"Privacy Policy",
    "type":"Privacy Policy",
    "description":"A privacy policy is a legal document that details how a website gathers, stores, shares, and sells data about its visitors. This data typically includes items such as a user's name, address, birthday, marital status, medical history, and consumer behavior. The specific contents of this document depend upon the laws in the legal jurisdiction in which your business operates. Most countries have their own set of guidelines regarding what information is eligible for collection, and how that information may be used.",
    "profile_image":"/privacy.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"privacy-policy"
},
{
    "title":"FAQ",
    "type":"FAQ",
    "description":"This page will Show you frequently ask questions.",
    "profile_image":"/faq.jpg",
    "author":"Bookingkoala",
    "status":1,
    "slug":"faq"
}
]
```

Comment: @Flimzy can you tell me how I will use it in my code

Comment: you need to changed from `err = json.Unmarshal(k.([]uint8), &rankings)` to `err = json.Unmarshal(k.(string), &rankings)` if `&ranking` has all values of type `string` .

Comment: @saddam it will showing me a error of `cannot use k.(string) (type string) as type []byte in argument to json.Unmarshal`

Comment: show me the `json` content which one  you have in `page.json`, I fix it.

Comment: @saddam see the json file. I want to write there `_id` field in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm here with solution to write JSON in file with append more columns, please follow the below code.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
)

type Page struct {
  Id           int    `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
  Title        string `json:"title" bson:"title"`
  Type         string `json:"type" bson:"type"`
  Description  string `json:"description" bson:"description"`
  ProfileImage string `json:"profile_image" bson:"profile_image"`
  DateTime     int64  `json:"date_time" bson:"date_time"`
  Author       string `json:"author" bson:"author"`
  Status       int    `json:"status" bson:"status"`
  Slug         string `json:"slug" bson:"slug"`
}

func main() {
   var data interface{}
   plan, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("page.json")
   err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(plan), &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var ranking = Page{}
    var rankings = []Page{}
    if sl, ok := data.([]interface{}); ok {
        var counter int = 0

        for _, val := range sl {
            counter = counter + 1
            md, _ := val.(map[string]interface{})
            md["_id"] = counter
            b, err := json.Marshal(md)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            // ********************* Unmarshal *********************
            err = json.Unmarshal(b, &ranking)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            rankings = append(rankings, ranking)

        }
    }

    rankingsJson, _ := json.Marshal(rankings)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("output.json", rankingsJson, 0644)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", rankings)
}
```

Comment: I updated the code and removed `jso`, it was just for JSON testing variable.

Comment: providing me this code you make my day ;)

Comment: There is one question from my side can we write multiple files using diffrent struct?

Comment: I think no cause only once we can write into file and when we will write another struct then it's going to be overwrite the previous struct values.

Comment: can you tell me about what is the meaning of `sl`here

Comment: `s1` is the only variable which contains value of interface `data`.

Comment: okay. Actually I created two files by removing `Page{}` with `interface{}` and `[]Page{}` with `[]interface{}`